# Slim Framework / php active record / twig conundrum, find all where field not equal to

Tags: twig, slim, phpactiverecord

Trying to get to grips with slim framework and phpactive record. Have searched the docs, here and google to no avail and tried several things.

I would like to retrieve all items from a table where a field is not set to a particular enumerator. Sounds simple and it should be.

```
    $data['labels'] = Label::find()->where('printed' != 'Y')->all();
```

The above fails with: **Message:** Couldn't find Label without an ID. I have also tried:

```
    $data['labels'] = Label::find('all','printed' != 'Y');
```

It just returns **one** record rather than all that meet the criteria.

In my twig template I have tried (which does nothing):

```
    {% for label in labels %}
     <td>{{ label.id }}</td>
     <td>{{ label.title }}</td>
     <td>{{ label.address }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
```

and (which prints the single record:

```
     <td>{{ labels.id }}</td>
     <td>{{ labels.title }}</td>
     <td>{{ labels.address }}</td>
```

thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) syntax should be one of the following:

```
Label::find("all", array("conditions" => array("label != ?", "Y")));
Label::all(array("conditions" => array("label != ?", "Y")));
```